# Display takes a while to come on after sleep and No sound from internal speakers in OS X, but everything is fine in Ubuntu

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, audio, speakers

## My Hardware

- Macbook Air Early 2008 (MacbookAir1,1)
- OS X Lion 10.7.5

## Problems

***1)*** **Display backlight is off for minutes after waking.**

When I wake up my MBA from a longer sleep or after being off for more than say around 15 minutes, I'll have to wait sometimes up to 5 minutes to use it, if I shine my flashlight through the logo on the back, or onto the screen, I can see that everything is still working perfectly, it's as if I had turned the brightness down to last setting, turning the brightness up with the F2 brightness hotkey doesn't make a difference, although the brightness bar in the little applet goes up. Also I seem to notice a direct dependency in time turned off to the amount of time it takes to come back on. I also know that it isn't still asleep, because, the 'breathing' light at the front goes out.

***2)*** **No Sound from Built-In Speakers**

This one is perhaps even more of an inconvenience, I don't see any sign of them in SysPrefs Sound Settings, or Audio MIDI Setup, however, I *do* hear the startup chime, so I knew they were okay. But once I boot into OS X, nothing. Only headphones show in Output Devices, even when said headphone jack is physically removed from the computer. I do however get sound through earphones. And even when they are plugged out, I have no restrictions in volume changing as I have seen with other people on the internet, also this laptop is not capable of digital audio out, so there will be no red light.

---

#### When I boot into a Ubuntu Live USB however, everything changes

Everything works like a charm, I can close my clamshell for as long as I want and it the screen pops up as soon as I open it, Speakers work wonderfully and so on.

---

## (Failed) Attempts taken at Resolving Issue

- Restarted Laptop
- Zapped the living daylights out of the PRAM
- Reset the SMC senseless
- Reset Sound Card from Terminal
- `fsck -fy`
- Unplugging/Replugging display ribbon cable
- ⌘+⌥+⎋
- Booting into both safe and single user modes
- Verifying/Repairing Disk Permissions in Disk Utility
- Fondling around the headphone jack with a toothpick/matchstick/Q-Tip/Needle
- Plugging in and out headphones repeatedly
- Blowing into headphone jack
- Taking apart computer and removing side port array (including headphone jack)
- Reinstalling firmware for BootRom and SMC

  - Well I attempted to do this, but was informed by yon macbook that I didn't need to and as such wasn't allowed to
- Battery Pull/ Power Drain
- Fresh Install of OS X Lion

---

### Ubuntu live USB, is the only thing I've tried that yielded any results, and I really don't want to resort to using it as my primary OS :(

EDIT: Internal Speakers actually show up in System Information..forgot to put that